# Is SSL certificate needed for Google and Facebook OAuth2 provider in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, oauth-2.0, facebook-authentication, google-authentication

I read a [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) how to add support for Google and Facebook `OAuth2` provider. One step in this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) is setting up SSL in the project. I don't have SSL certificate on my hosting. It is still possible to implement these providers without SSL certificate? I don't want any security warnings on my site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need SSL in your application in order to connect with third party OAuth providers. Of course you will be exposing the security of your authentication cookies because they will be sent as cleartext on each request.

So even if this is not a requirement, it is strongly recommended.